# Two clicks - different actions (same div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hope someone could help!
I have some divs (using bootstrap) like:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row" id="r2">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="block-in-div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="block-in-div"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="block-in-div"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="block-in-div"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="block-in-div"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="block-in-div"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on some div it should randomly get some background color.
When I click on another div, previous should reset its background, and newly clicked div should get its random background.
Whith this issues everything is clear.

*I can`t get how to do next: I clicked on div, it changes its colour, I click again and it should become bigger.*

Color randomizer:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var r=Math.floor(Math.random() * (256));
    var g=Math.floor(Math.random() * (256));
    var b=Math.floor(Math.random() * (256));
    var color = '#' + r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16);
    return color;};
```

Reset background:

```
function cancelBg() {
let selectedBlocks = $("div.block-in-div");
$.each(selectedBlocks,function(key,value){
    selectedBlocks[key].style.background = "none";
});};
```

Main function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".block-in-div").click(function () {
    cancelBg();
    $(this).css("background", getRandomColor());
});});
```

Trying smth like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".block-in-div").click(function () {
    var state = 1;
    return function () {
        cancelBg();
        if(state===1){
            $(this).css("background", getRandomColor());
            state=2;
        }
        else if(state===2){
            /*$(this).addClass("active");*/
            state=1;
        }
    };
}());});
```

.active just for test and it is simply:

```
.active{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Please help!
Be the force with you! :)

Comment: Use snippet in order to create a working demo (or jsfiddle if it's simpler for you)

Comment: Sure, with jsfiddle would be better. https://jsfiddle.net/momvnzgs/

Comment: I think this will help you https://jsfiddle.net/momvnzgs/8/

Comment: Thanks, this jsfiddle is very helpful. But still don`t understand how to reset backgrounds if i clock on another div. My target is: 1st click on block A - change color (e.g. green), another click (on block B) - change color(e.g. yellow), again click on block A (change color e.g. red) second click on this block A (with red color) - it becomes bigger..

Comment: updated fiddle check this- https://jsfiddle.net/momvnzgs/10/

Comment: Thank you!!! Still need next scheme e.g.: click div A - background red, click div B - background blue (and A`s background is none), click div C - background  blue (all other div`s background is none), click div B - background orange (others background is none), click B again - background still orange and its size changed (no matter how). Your jsfiddle should help, but if you got ideas- i would be appreciate!

Comment: @Arvind Dhakad post above was for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding a class when the div was clicked first.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".block-in-div").click(function () {          
        return function () {
            cancelBg();
            if(!$(this).hasClass('not-resized')) {
                $(this).css("background", getRandomColor());
                $(this).addClass('not-resized');
            }
            else if ($(this).hasClass('not-resized')) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(this).removeClass('not-resized');
            }
        };
    }());
});
```

If you need to reset the state on click on other div you can just add $(".block-in-div").removeClass('not-resized'); at the end.

Note 1: Adding active class like you did will have lower priority than the size on original class (add an !important as a temporal fix to see the changes or even better... make a stronger selector).

Note 2: If I didn't get the requirements right pls. tell me.

Comment: If I make var state global: first click changes color, but when i make second click on another block it changes its size. If click second time on the same block it changes size and reset background. My target is: 1st click on block A - change color (e.g. green), another click (on block B) - change color(e.g. yellow), again click on block A (change color e.g. red) second click on this block A (with red color) - it becomes bigger...

Comment: Ok... let me see the fiddle (I see you added now).

Comment: @user7342510 Edited answer. Tell me if I didn't get what you needed right.

Comment: Below I wrote what I got but still got problem. Anyway - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!
Mold something like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ca6dt72a/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".block-in-div").click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('tofull') &&  !$(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass("active tofull");
        $(this).css("background", "none");
    }
    else{
        cancelBg();
        let clr = "#"+((1<<24) * Math.random()|0).toString(16);
        $(this).css("background", clr);
        $(this).addClass("noColor tofull");
    }
});
```

});

Still got some problems with working but got ideas how to fix it.
Problem is: Click block A (become red), click B (yellow), click C (green), click A again - size changes but no background